# using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting and Custom ScaleView/Zoom

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a C# application that is using the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting library to display live data input from a test.  I need to position the graph so that the x axis spans from 0 to 10, and with the press of a page buttom, it needs to scroll to 5 to 15, 10 to 20, 15 to 25; etc. Setting ScaleView and/or Zoom have done the trick, but when I begin to add data to the graph, it begins resizing automatically.  I am able to page through the graph using ScaleView.Position = int NewPosition, however, I need to figure out how to keep the view from autoscaling.

Can this be done?

EDIT:
Found the issue! Turns out ScaleView will zoom just fine as long as you have a Series with points that roughly follow the scale.  For example: if you add a line for reference with point 0, 10 and point 10, 10 (or even 5, 10) and your scale is 1, then the graph will autoadjust to fit this larger scale.  To fix this, you must put a line with points 0,0 and 0,1 and 0,2 etc, or any other points that are close enough together to ensure the scale stays the way you need it to be.

Hope this clarifies and thanks for anyone who looked.